# PyCharm can't find module 'math'

Tags: python, pycharm

My environment PyCharm 4.5 with Python 3.5

[image]

It can run successfully, but warning that can't find module `math`, and can't complete the method tips.

I had tried this:

```
import imp
imp.find_module('math')

(<_io.BufferedReader name='/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/math.cpython-35m-darwin.so'>, '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/math.cpython-35m-darwin.so', ('.cpython-35m-darwin.so', 'rb', 3))
```

I'm new to Python, I think this is no `math.py`. How do I resolve it?

Comment: Just to make sure. Are you doing this properly: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/configuring_interpreter.html

Comment: As a side-note, I'm more than willing to believe that this is the math module that you are seeking, since `math` is [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/math.html).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> As a side-note, I'm more than willing to believe that this is the math module that you are seeking, since math is built-in.

Yeah, Python 3.5 has no 'math.py', it's 'math.cpython-35m-darwin.so'

I switch to Python 3.4.3 , and It's OK.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm 4.X does not fully support Python 3.5.
Update to PyCharm 5 and your issue will be gone.